# Can I say "a great..........., greater than..."?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

I have written the following sentence: "*I intend to put a great effort into preparing for the XXX, greater than that expected from XXX*".

Is this sentence grammatically correct and appropriately structured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of `“a great…, greater than…”` is correct, though you need not write `that` after `than`. However, I sense something wrong with the subject of the sentence.

You have written `"XXX"` in two places and that makes me believe that you want to denote the same thing by both the `"XXX"`s. If `"XXX"` is something like an exam, for example, the GRE, then your sentence would be as follows:

> I intend to put a great effort into preparing for the GRE, greater
>   than expected for the GRE.

Notice that we have used `"for"` here.

If you want to denote two different things by the `"XXX"`s, for example

> I intend to put a great effort into preparing for the GRE, greater
>   than expected from me.

then, you would use `"from"`.